# DIA SDK how to get parent function of FuncDebugStart / FuncDebugEnd?

Tags: windows, debugging, debug-symbols, dia-sdk

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6d4y5690.aspx) for `SymTagFuncDebugStart` and `SymTagFuncDebugEnd` state that calling `IDiaSymbol::get_lexicalParent` will return a symbol for the enclosing function.  I interpret this as I will get an `IDiaSymbol` whose `get_symTag` method returns `SymTagFunction`.  However, when I do this it returns me the `SymTagCompiland` and not the function.  So the documentation appears wrong, but worse I'm not sure how to actually tie the `SymTagFuncDebugStart` and `SymTagFuncDebugEnd` to the containing `SymTagFunction`.

Does anyone know?  A few dumps suggest that `SymTagFuncDebugStart` and `SymTagFuncDebugEnd` always come immediately after the corresponding `SymTagFunction` when enumerating the symbols via `IEnumSymbols`.  Or put another way, that if `IDiaSymbol::get_symIndexId` returns `n` for the function, it will return `n+1` and `n+2` respectively for the func debug start and func debug end.

But I can't be sure this is always true, and this seems unreliable and hackish.

Does anyone have any suggestions on the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working eventually.  The problem is that when you enumerate all the symbols in the global scope using `SymTagNull`, you will find the `FuncDebugStart` and `FuncDebugEnd` symbols.  The lexical parent of these symbols is the global scope, because it's the "parent" in the sense that it vended you the pointers to the `FuncDebugStart` and `FuncDebugEnd` symbols.

If you get the `FuncDebugStart` and `FuncDebugEnd` by calling `findChildren` on an actual `SymTagFunction` symbol, however, then its lexical parent will in fact be the original function.  So this was an issue of unclear documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Could you paste your code here? I guess there is something wrong in your code. Call `get_lexicalParent` on `SymTagFuncDebugStart` and `SymTagFuncDebugEnd` should return the symbol associated the enclosing function (`SymTagFunction`).

Comment: I ended up figuring it out.  I updated this question with the answer that I arrived at.